# Chaining async functions with pure React?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, method-chaining

I'd like to know if there is a way to chain async functions with React only. I know how to do it with Redux, but wondering if there's a method using only React.

Basically, I'd like to call the function `computerMove()`, but only after `this.state.myMove` is set to `false`. Something like this:

```
this.setState({ myTurn: false }).then(() => {
            this.computerMove();
          });
```

(Above code doesn't work, but that's what I'm trying to do).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not pass a callback to `setState`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous and has the ability to fire off a callback:

```
this.setState({ myTurn: false }, this.computerMove);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate, which is what you want. It passes the props & state as they were before the last render. Check if the myTurn value has changed.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (!this.state.myTurn && this.state.myTurn != prevState.myTurn) {
    this.computerMove();
  }
}
```